# how to change font size in package exercise

Tags: fontsize, exercises

I would like to decrease the font size when typesetting the answers to exercises using the package `exercise`. Something like this:

```
{\tiny
\shipoutAnswer
}
```

But this doesn't work. I can't find how to do it in the package manual.

Any hints?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide full examples, not just fragments of code

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option; since no MWE was provided I provide the code required to change the answer font as well as the answer header; change `\AnswerFont` to the desired font specification (I chose `\tiny` just for the example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\newcommand\AnswerFont{\tiny}

% change font for answers text
\renewcommand\AtBeginAnswer{\AnswerFont}
% change font for answers header
\renewcommand\AnswerHeader{\medskip\centerline{{\AnswerFont\textbf{
Answer of \ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB}\smallskip}}}
% change font for answers list header
\renewcommand\AnswerListHeader{{\AnswerFont\textbf{\AnswerListName\
(\ExerciseListName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)\ ---\ }}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
    Some introductory text.
    \Question \label{first}The first question?
    \Question \label{second}The second question?
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}
    The answer to Question~\ref{first}.
\end{Answer}
\begin{Answer}
    The answer to Question~\ref{second}.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Luis You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer, if you consider it solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).